# Sending user-dependent scheduled emails with celery and django?

Tags: django, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I'd like for my web-app to send weekly / monthly emails to the users - how would I limit celery to only send scheduled emails to the users that "opt-in"?

I installed django-celery-beat and I can configure a cron job in the admin interface, but not only to specific users

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a field to your `User` model to store if the user has opted-in or out for emails. Below is pseudo code and assumes you have extended Django with a custom `User` model of your own.

models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    email_opt_in = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Other code ...
```

tasks.py:

```
from .models import User

@app.task
def send_daily_email():
    # Get all users that are active and opted-in for emails
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, email_opt_in=True)

    for user in users:
        # Code to generate and send email
```